# How to filter the rows of a dataframe based on the presence of the column values in a separate dataframe and append columns from the second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes:

Dataframe 1:

| Fruit | Vegetable |
| --- | --- |
| Mango | Spinach |
| Apple | Kale |
| Watermelon | Squash |
| Peach | Zucchini |

Dataframe 2:

| Item | Price/lb |
| --- | --- |
| Mango | 2 |
| Spinach | 1 |
| Apple | 4 |
| Peach | 2 |
| Zucchini | 1 |

I want to discard the rows from the dataframe 1 when both the columns are not present in the 'Item' series of dataframe 2 and I want to create the following dataframe3 based on dataframes 1 & 2:

| Fruit | Vegetable | Combination Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mango | Spinach | 3 |
| Peach | Zucchini | 3 |

The third column in dataframe 3 is the sum of the item prices from dataframe 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `melt`,`merge` and `unstack`:

```
(df1[(df1['Fruit'].isin(df2['Item'])) & (df1['Vegetable'].isin(df2['Item']))]
    .reset_index()
    .melt(id_vars = 'index',value_vars = ['Fruit','Vegetable'])
    .merge(df2,left_on='value',right_on = 'Item')
    .drop(columns = 'Item')
    .set_index(['index','variable']).unstack(level = 1)
    .transform(lambda g: g.assign(Combination_Price=g.xs('Price/lb',axis=1,level=0).sum(axis=1)))
)
```

produces combination price and breakdown by ingredient, just in case

```
            value               Price/lb           Combination_Price
variable    Fruit   Vegetable   Fruit   Vegetable   
index                   
0           Mango   Spinach     2       1         3
3           Peach   Zucchini    2       1         3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two steps:

1. Mask your dataframe1 such that it only contains rows where both fruit and vegetable exits in dataframe2.Item
2. Use `Series.map` to obtain the values associated with the remaining rows, and add them together to get the combination price.

```
# Make our df2 information easier to work with. 
#  It is now a Series whose index is the Item and values are the prices. 
#  This allows us to work with it like a dictionary
>>> item_pricing = df2.set_index("Item")["Price/lb"]
>>> items = item_pricing.index

# get rows where BOTH fruit is in items & Vegetable is in items
>>> mask = df1["Fruit"].isin(items) & df1["Vegetable"].isin(items)
>>> subset = df1.loc[mask].copy()  # .copy() tells pandas we want this subset to be independent of the larger dataframe
>>> print(subset)
   Fruit Vegetable
0  Mango   Spinach
3  Peach  Zucchini

# On each column (fruit and vegetable) use .map to obtain the price of those items
#  then sum those columns together into a single price
>>> subset["combo_price"] = subset.apply(lambda s: s.map(item_pricing)).sum(axis=1)
>>> print(subset)
   Fruit Vegetable  combo_price
0  Mango   Spinach            3
3  Peach  Zucchini            3
```

All together with no comments:

```
item_pricing = df2.set_index("Item")["Price/lb"]
items = item_pricing.index

mask = df1["Fruit"].isin(items) & df1["Vegetable"].isin(items)
subset = df1.loc[mask].copy()
subset["combo_price"] = subset.apply(lambda s: s.map(item_pricing)).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Such an elegant solution! It covers most of it. However, if there's a NaN value in the 'Price/lb' column, the last line of the code doesn't work.

Comment: I tried nansum(), but its not the solution.

Comment: Well, that depends on how you want to calculate the price of a combination that contains a `NaN`. The code here will result in the combination of anything that has a `NaN` to remain `NaN` which I think is appropriate. What did you have in mind?

Comment: I am thinking about replacing NaN values with 0.

Comment: replace the first line `item_pricing = df2.set_index("Item")["Price/lb"]` with this `item_pricing = df2.set_index("Item")["Price/lb"].fillna(0)` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two inner joins, as shown below.  The final result is contained in df3.

```
df_temp = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='Fruit', right_on='Item', how='inner')
df3 = pd.merge(df_temp, df2, left_on='Vegetable', right_on='Item', how='inner')
df3['Combined price'] = df3['Price/lb_x'] + df3['Price/lb_y']
df3.drop(columns = ['Item_x','Price/lb_x','Item_y','Price/lb_y'], inplace = True)
```